# Intellij setup for Java graphics

Tags: java, intellij-idea, graphics, import

How to write the BouncingBall program in Intellij . . . I'm trying to use multiple sources of information to get a good grasp of Java. To this end, I've taken the Udacity Intro to Java course, downloaded Intellij-IDEA, use the Sololearn App, and have been watching a series of lectures posted to Youtube by Stanford University. I'm trying to copy the program from Mehran Sahami's tenth lecture in the series https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YpZCKVG4s5k&t=1995s but can't get it to run. I'm assuming that there are elements required for it to run that are not being properly imported or invoked. But, being a novice, at both Java and Intellij, I'm not sure where to start.

Here's how my code starts, anything obvious leap out? Is anything here calling for files or classes I need to install into the source or project folders, JDK, or elsewhere?

```
<import acm.program.*.r[]
    public class BouncingBall extends GraphicsProgram{
       private static final int DIAM_BALL=30;
       private static final double GRAVITY=3;
       private static final int DELAY=50;
       private static final double X_START=DIAM_BALL/2;
       private static final double Y_START=100;
```

Certain terms in the IDE are shown in red and the tooltip indicates "Cannot resolve symbol(or method)". This also suggests to me that the tool cannot reach the required classes or files. So . . . how do I fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, this is the compile-time error message generated: "Error:(1, 1) java: class, interface, or enum expected"

Comment: I found a comment on Youtube stating that "awesome stuff again.. this .acm libery is a libery used @ stanford.. to bad tho..".  Well, the grammar and spelling here is not encouraging, but is the idea correct? Is the program drawing on resources available to the development environment in the lecture hall, but not to every JDK? Hmm, I'm off to research "Java GraphicsProgram". Lastly, is it considered gauche to comment on one's own question in this way? Just trying to get the useful information to anyone who might like to answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm, found an ACM jar file, an archive containing the acm packages, including GraphicsProgram, at this site: http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/  Unfortunately, placing the file in various folders in my project hasn't helped. Also, the file is designated and "executable jar file", but I can't seem to get it to execute.

Comment: The jar is a library, not executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.util.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class BouncingBall extends GraphicsProgram {
     private static final int DIAM_BALL = 30; 
     ...
```

The imports just be folded in the video.

Also download the acm.jar into your project directory and right click the jar file, select `Add as Library` will add the jar file to project in intellij.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I got it added. Now I have to trace down the other errors, but the project was pretty much a non-starter without that. Hopefully, most of these are typos or problems seeing the source code.